# How to find my Windows OS is x64 or ia64?

Tags: windows

When I scan few executables in my windows directory with [ProtectionID](http://pid.gamecopyworld.com/), I happened to scan Windows Explorer. And the results are given below.

```
Scanning -> C:\Windows\explorer.exe
File Type : 64-Bit Exe (Subsystem : Win GUI / 2), Size : 2871808 (02BD200h) Byte(s)
[!] Warning : Cpu is AMD, this file is for IA64 (incompatible)
[x] Warning - FileAlignment seems wrong.. no solution calculated (using NULL)
[File Heuristics] -> Flag : 00000000000001001101000000000000 (0x0004D000)
[CompilerDetect] -> Visual C++ 9.0 (Visual Studio 2008)
[!] File appears to have no protection or is using an unknown protection
- Scan Took : 0.548 Second(s)
```

I know that my processor is Core 2 Duo and it's x64 architecture as resulted in warning flag. But the OS I've installed is Windows 7 x64. The above results raise me a question that my OS is x64 or IA64? How can I find that?

**Update**
In the latest build of ProtectionID this false warning seems fixed.

Comment: As far as I can see only the Server editions of Windows have an explicit version for the Itanium architecture (aka IA64), with Win7 64-bit just supporting the "usual" x64 instruction set. Are you *100%* sure you've installed the 64-bit version of Windows 7? And are you *100%* sure your CPU is defintely 64-bit (I've not checked if all Core 2 Duos were). Oh, and does the `exe` *work* (I'm assuming so else you'd have serious OS trouble)? If so, I'd be dubious that the software is given a valid reading, check with something else.

Comment: The CPU type should be in the environment variable `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`, and `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` in the command prompt should give you `AMD64` (as you say you're using a Core 2 Duo). `msinfo32.exe` should also have a "System Type" field, which says `x64-based PC` for me on a x86-64 processor. I'm not sure how/why you have a IA64 system binary...

Comment: That, or ProtectionID is broken.

Comment: What version of ProtectionID?

Comment: @DMA57361 - I've Core 2 Duo E7300. I've Windows 7 x64 Ultimate. As per my taskmgr, around 40% of my processes running in x86 compatibility mode i.e., with a *32 suffix after the image name.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Having v0.6.4.0 as Bob -'s snapshot in the second response.

Comment: Jones:  Your CPU is x64 (w/ x86 compatibility), not IA64.  The two instruction sets are completely different, so you can't run x64 apps on an IA64 processor, and vice-versa.  The answer here is in what HARDWARE you have, since the IA64 version of Windows (only server builds exist) wouldn't run on your hardware anyways.

Comment: IA64 CPUs are very expensive and hard to find, unless you're running some very old servers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The CPU type should be in the environment variable `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`, and `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` in the command prompt should give you `AMD64` on a x86-64 processor. msinfo32.exe should also have a "System Type" field, which says x64-based PC for me on a x86-64 processor. I'm not sure how/why you have a IA64 system binary...

---

It seems to be a problem with ProtectionID:

```
Scanning -> C:\Windows\explorer.exe
File Type : 64-Bit Exe (Subsystem : Win GUI / 2), Size : 2871808 (02BD200h) Byte(s)
[!] Warning : Cpu is AMD, this file is for IA64 (incompatible)
[x] Warning - FileAlignment seems wrong.. no solution calculated (using NULL)
[File Heuristics] -> Flag : 00000000000001001101000000000000 (0x0004D000)
[CompilerDetect] -> Visual C++ 9.0 (Visual Studio 2008)
[!] File appears to have no protection or is using an unknown protection
- Scan Took : 0.828 Second(s)
```

But in the PE Stuff tab:

[[image: Screenshot (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYdFF.png)

Comment: Sailing in the same boat! Additionally the Misc Tools ->Misc Tools/System info -> Processor architecture says 'Intel(x86) based'

Answer (score 5):

As the first comment on the Q notes, there is no IA64 build of Windows 7. For an IA64 version you must use server.

Perhaps the most reliable way to determine this information is with WMI and the classes [Win32_OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Win32_ComputerSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Using PowerShell and the `gwmi` alias for [`Get-WmiObject`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx):

```
PS> gwmi win32_computersystem -computer one,two,localhost| ft __SERVER,systemtype

__SERVER                                          systemtype
--------                                          ----------
ONE                                               X86-based PC
TWO                                               x64-based PC
THREE                                             x64-based PC
```

so One isn't 64bit, and the other two are both x64, none are IA64.<sup>1</sup> Then:

```
PS [64] E:\ #12> gwmi win32_operatingsystem -comp one,two,localhost| ft __SERVER,caption

__SERVER                                          caption
--------                                          -------
ONE                                               Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Standard
TWO                                               Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
THREE                                             Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
```

So One is Win2k8 32bit, Two is Win2k8R2 64bit and Three (localhost) is Win7 64bit.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't have an IA64 system to check what value the `SystemType` field will have.

Answer (score 3):

The IA64 architecture is completely different from the x86-64 (aka AMD64) architecture, which is what most people mean when they say 64-bit. So even if there was a IA64-compatible version of Windows 7 (which, as other people have pointed out, there isn't<sup>1</sup>), it would require an [Itanium processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium), you wouldn't be able to install it on a Core 2 Duo or any other x86-64 system.

Edit: also, an alternative way to get the processor architecture with WMI (from command prompt or PS):

```
wmic CPU get Architecture
```

`CPU` is an alias for the [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, and the possible values<sup>2</sup> are (meanings in parentheses):

- `0` (x86)
- `9` (x86-64)
- `6` (Itanium)

<sup>1</sup> The last client version to support IA64 was Windows XP; [Windows Server 2008 R2 will be the last server version](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-pulls-the-plug-on-future-itanium-support/5796).
<sup>2</sup> There's a few others, for architectures like MIPS, Alpha and PowerPC, but those are mostly there for legacy reasons; see the MSDN article above for full details.

Comment: @William.Ebe A standard x86-64 CPU, as expected. The problem likely lies with ProtectionID, then. Glad I could help. Please remember to accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the green checkmark outline next to it.

Answer (score -1):

Open a Command window and run the following:

```
C:\>set | findstr ARCH

PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
```

Comment: Listing all variables then filtering out one is not efficient when you already know the name. Simply use the environment variable directly, as I described on my answer.